# Redundant country flags after ng build

Tags: angular, build

After doing ng build --prod, my dist folder includes a lot of country flags in SVG format. What could be the reason here and how can I exclude them?
[image: dist folder content]

My dependencies

[image]

My devDependencies

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from [flag-icon-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flag-icon-css) package. You can either use/remove it to solve the issue.

The new package for this is going to be [flag-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flag-icons)

Also to minify the number of assets imported you need to play around with importing the scss files directly, instead of importing `flag-icons.min.css` (which imports all the flags) instead try importing the scss files and try to conditionally add the flag icons.

In the docs it mentions

[_flag-icons-list.scss](https://github.com/lipis/flag-icons/blob/0da24d6a0ded8c99316024a199c02976bafe7e95/sass/_flag-icons-list.scss)

> To have only specific countries in the css file, remove the ones that you don't need from the flag-icons-list.less file and build it again.

code

```
@import "variables";
@import "flag-icons-base"; /* contains the mixins */

/* @import "flag-icons-list"; */
/* instead of just importing the list of values from the above scss file, try include the code that you actually need, it might fix your issue */
...
```